# android Problem with checkBox with baseAdapter

Tags: android

I have used baseAdepter for display three View in list .
first two are textView and last is checkBox View .
But when i going to check the checkBox and scroll the list ,after  in the some specific number of item ,the other check box is automatic checked unaseptedlly ..

i don't have idea Why this kind of thing is occur .

Is anybody der who know the solution of it ..

here is my code for baseadepter ..

```
private static class AdepterGetUnit extends BaseAdapter{
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public AdepterGetUnit (Context context){
   mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {

    positionList  = sharedPreferences.getInt(UnitScreen.POSITION, 0);           

    if(positionList==0){currentListLenght=ArrayHolder.dbSpeed.size();}
    else if(positionList==1){currentListLenght=ArrayHolder.dbAngle.size();}
    else if(positionList==2){currentListLenght=listTemperature.length;}
    else if(positionList==3){currentListLenght=ArrayHolder.dbLenght.size();}
    else if(positionList==4){currentListLenght=ArrayHolder.dbWeightMass.size();}
    else if(positionList==5){currentListLenght=ArrayHolder.dbPressure.size();}
    else if(positionList==6){currentListLenght=ArrayHolder.dbPower.size();}
    else if(positionList==7){currentListLenght=ArrayHolder.dbCurrency.size();}
    else if(positionList==8){currentListLenght=ArrayHolder.dbDataSize.size();}
    else if(positionList==9){currentListLenght=ArrayHolder.dbVolume.size();}
    else if(positionList==10){currentListLenght=ArrayHolder.dbTime.size();}
    else if(positionList==11){currentListLenght=ArrayHolder.dbArea.size();}
    else if(positionList==12){currentListLenght=ArrayHolder.dbCoocking.size();}
    return  currentListLenght;
 }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
       if (convertView==null){
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_edit_unit, null);
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_show_units);
           holder.textTotle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_unit);
           holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
           convertView.setTag(holder);
       }
       else
       {
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }
//           positionList  = sharedPreferences.getInt(UnitScreen.POSITION, 0);           

       switch (positionList) {
    case 0:
        holder.text.setText(ArrayHolder.dbSpeed.get(position));
        holder.textTotle.setText(ArrayHolder.dbSpeedUnit.get(position));
        txtUnitTitleName.setText("Speed");
        break;
    case 1:
        holder.text.setText(ArrayHolder.dbAngle.get(position));
        holder.textTotle.setText(ArrayHolder.dbAngleUnit.get(position));
        txtUnitTitleName.setText("Angle");
        break;
    case 2:
        holder.text.setText(ArrayHolder.dbTemperature.get(position));
        holder.textTotle.setText(ArrayHolder.dbTemperatureUnit.get(position));
        txtUnitTitleName.setText("Temperature");
       break;
    case 3:
        holder.text.setText(ArrayHolder.dbLenght.get(position));
        holder.textTotle.setText(ArrayHolder.dbLenghtUnit.get(position));
        txtUnitTitleName.setText("Lenght");
        break;
    case 4:
        holder.text.setText(ArrayHolder.dbWeightMass.get(position));
        holder.textTotle.setText(ArrayHolder.dbWeightMassUnit.get(position));
        txtUnitTitleName.setText("Weight/Mass");
        break;
    case 5:
        holder.text.setText(ArrayHolder.dbPressure.get(position));
        holder.textTotle.setText(ArrayHolder.dbPressureUnit.get(position));
        txtUnitTitleName.setText("Pressure");
        break;
    case 6:
        holder.text.setText(ArrayHolder.dbPower.get(position));
        holder.textTotle.setText(ArrayHolder.dbPowerUnit.get(position));
        txtUnitTitleName.setText("Power");
        break;
    case 7: 
        holder.text.setText(ArrayHolder.dbCurrency.get(position));
        holder.textTotle.setText(ArrayHolder.dbCurrencyUnit.get(position));
        if(!holder.checkBox.isChecked())
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        else
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);   
        txtUnitTitleName.setText("Currency");
        break;
    case 8:
        holder.text.setText(ArrayHolder.dbDataSize.get(position));
        holder.textTotle.setText(ArrayHolder.dbDataSizeUnit.get(position));
        txtUnitTitleName.setText("DataSize");
        break;
    case 9:
        holder.text.setText(ArrayHolder.dbVolume.get(position));
        holder.textTotle.setText(ArrayHolder.dbVolumeUnit.get(position));
        txtUnitTitleName.setText("Volume");
        break;
    case 10:
        holder.text.setText(ArrayHolder.dbTime.get(position));
        holder.textTotle.setText(ArrayHolder.dbTimeUnit.get(position));
        txtUnitTitleName.setText("Time");
        break;
    case 11:
        holder.text.setText(ArrayHolder.dbArea.get(position));
        holder.textTotle.setText(ArrayHolder.dbAreaUnit.get(position));
        txtUnitTitleName.setText("Area");
        break;
    case 12:
        holder.text.setText(ArrayHolder.dbCoocking.get(position));
        txtUnitTitleName.setText("Coocking");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }       

    return convertView;
}
static class ViewHolder {

    TextView text ,textTotle;
    ImageView icon;
    CheckBox checkBox;         
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position-1;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position-1;
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below. Your answer is right, I just edited it.

```
package com.android.diseaseRating;
import java.util.Vector;

import com.android.diseaseRating.db.DBConnect;
import com.android.diseaseRating.settings.SettingsList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ColorPickerBase1 extends BaseAdapter{

public ColorPickerBase1(Context context , Vector<String> colorName ,Vector<String> colorHex) {
layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

this.colorHex = colorHex;
this.colorName = colorName;

dbConnect = new DBConnect(context, Bean.DATABASE_NAME);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return colorName.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override      
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    viewHolder holder ;
    if(convertView==null){
        holder = new viewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_color_picker, null);

        holder.imgColorView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgViewColor);
        holder.txtColorName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtColorName);
        holder.chkBoxColorCked = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkBOx);

        boolean stop=true;
        if(SettingsList.SETTING)
            holder.chkBoxColorCked.setEnabled(false);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (viewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    System.out.println("TEH POSITION IS "+position ) ;
    System.out.println("TEH COLOR IS "+colorHex.get(position) ) ;

    if (position == 801 || position == 802 || position == 803
            || position == 1009 || position == 1011 || position == 1013
            || position == 1012 || position == 1017 || position == 1018
            || position == 1019 || position == 1024 || position == 1026
            || position == 1027 || position == 1028 || position == 1029
            || position == 1030 || position == 1029 || position == 1030
            || position == 1049 || position == 1068 || position == 1076
            || position == 1082) {        
    }
    else{
        try {
            holder.imgColorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"
                    + colorHex.get(position)));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        holder.txtColorName.setText("" + colorName.get(position));

    }

    holder.chkBoxColorCked.setTag(position);
    holder.chkBoxColorCked.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnChkListner);


    if(Bean.tempVector.get(position)){
        holder.chkBoxColorCked.setChecked(true);
    }
    else{
        holder.chkBoxColorCked.setChecked(false);
    }

    return convertView; 
}

CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener btnChkListner = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
    {
        //s("onCheckedChanged", "onCheckedChanged");
        final   int  positionChecked = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();
        //System.out.println("Position ====="+positionChecked);
        if(buttonView.isChecked())
        {                    
            Bean.colorRangeOnePicker1.add(positionChecked);
            Bean.tempVector.set(positionChecked, true);

            if(Bean.colorRangeOnePicker1.size()>2){
                Bean.colorRangeOnePicker1.remove(0);

//                  String SQL  = "UPDATE DisplaySettings SET range1color1 = '"+Bean.colorRangeOnePicker1.get(0) +"',range1color2 ='"+Bean.colorRangeOnePicker1.get(1)+"' where id ='"+ImageDisplay.SettingID+"'";
//                  
//                  dbConnect.execNonQuery(SQL);

            }
            System.out.println("COLOR RANGE ONE  IS "+Bean.colorRangeOnePicker1);
            //System.out.println("IN IF ...IS CHEKED ");
        }
        else{          
             Bean.tempVector.set(positionChecked, false);
        }


        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){

        }
    }
};


LayoutInflater layoutInflater ;


class viewHolder{
    ImageView imgColorView;
    TextView txtColorName;
    CheckBox chkBoxColorCked;
}

Vector<String > colorName;
Vector<String> colorHex;

    DBConnect dbConnect;
}
```